# How to fill df2 with data from df1 by matching column values from df1 which match df2 index and column names

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a large dataframe `df1` with many data columns, two of which are `dates` and `colNum`.  I have built a second dataframe `df2` which spans the date range and `colNum` of `df1`.  I now want to fill `df2` with a third column (any of the many other data columns) of `df1` which meet the criteria of `dates` and `colNum` from `df1` that match `dateIndex` and `colNum` of `df2`.

I've tried various incarnations of `MERGE` with no success.

I can loop through the combinations, but `df1` is very large (270k, 2k) so it takes forever to do fill one `df2` from one of `df1`'s columns, let alone all of them.

Slow looping version

```py
dataList = ['revt']
for i in dataList:
    goodRows = df1.index[~np.isnan(df1[i])].tolist()
    for j in goodRows:
        df2.loc[df1['dates'][j], str(df1['colNum'][j])] = df1[i][j]
```

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz3jz.png)

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAXNl.png)

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `to_clipboard`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-do-i-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-my-existing-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

convert index to column e.g

`df1.reset_index() #as per your statement date seems to be in index 
df2.rest_index()
df2 = pd.merge(df2, df1, on = ['dateIndex', 'colNum'], how = 'left')` #keep either "left" or "inner" as per your convenience

**update**
rather you can keep date in index and in pd.merge there is a option to join via index too

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this will produce a 3-column DF (once I drop the index) rather than a matrix DF based on dateIndex and colNum - sorry if that wasn't clear in my question